# Efficiency when handling Core Data Model Object

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data

I'm retro-fitting core data around an existing project and I would like to know which is better for efficiency reasons.

a) Create a model object with an attribute that is of the type of my current model class, then make the object transformable to NSData.

or

b) Subclass NSManagedObject, give it all the ivars of my model object and on fetch / insert do a translating to a model object (fetch) or an NSManagedObject (insert).

Thanks,

Tim

Comment: How are you creating these existing model objects? Do you plan to keep them around too? Efficiency of fetching or inserting? In what ways do you access and use the data?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you don't really understand the purpose of core data. Core data is a mature object graph that can be attached to a persistent store, like SQLite. Whenever you fetch something out of core data, it is already a model object. You use the NSManagedObject as your models, there's no real reason to pull the data out of the NSManagedObject and into a different object.

Before you go further, I recommend that you take a hard look at http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/cdprogrammingguide.html